# What is an alternative to word-break : break-word; in CSS since it's deprecated and invalid by W3C standards?

Tags: css, word-break

I don't want the words to be break, but if the word is too long and the word could be breaked.¨

I used `word-break: break-word;`

But when validating the CSS in this it gives error: The value break-word is deprecated

I used alternatives offered in StackOverflow:

```
word-break: break-all;  it breaks all words even if the word is not that long-
word-break: normal;
word-break: initial;

word-wrap: break-word;
word-wrap: break-spaces;

overflow-wrap: normal;
overflow-wrap: break-word;

line-break: normal;
line-break: strict;
line-break: anywhere;
```

But none of them works. Either they break all the words - even short ones - or they don't break long words when the word is extending the div-space.

The only code that works is `word-break: break-word;` but that is deprecated.

**What is an alternative to `word-break: break-word;` ??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and found that `overflow-wrap: anywhere` worked for my case. Credit: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2682#issuecomment-438693305

Comment: Note: Browser support is limited for [`overflow-wrap: anywhere`](https://caniuse.com/?search=overflow-wrap%3A%20anywhere) while [`word-break: break-word;`](https://caniuse.com/?search=word-break%3A%20break-word%3B) has quite good support since Firefox finally implemented it